# Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rospy] - robotiq ros driver dependencies

Tags: dependencies, ubuntu-16.04, ros, modbus-tcp, rospy

I am going to install ros driver for robotiq gripper as indicated in http://wiki.ros.org/robotiq
But for installing Modbus TCP dependencies (`rosdep install robotiq_modbus_tcp`), I have the following issue:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
robotiq_modbus_tcp: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rospy]

PS: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (kinetic),

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me with the issue...

Comment: Have you checked out the correct branch (in your case kinetic) after cloning the directory? `git branch` should show you `kinetic-devel` and in case it does not you will have to switch to it with `git checkout kinetic-devel`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, indeed I am in the correct branch. But shows the error that I mentioned in the question. I have created a new catkin_ws to have a fresh workspace, the error still exists. I have done the same thing in a different PC, then it is working. I have the impression it would be related to python stuff. But I have checked the python version for both PC it is the same (Python 2.7.12). I have no idea what can be different that causes this error ...

Comment: One possible explanation would be that on the other computer you have either installed `rospy` or it automatically sources the workspace (e.g. `.bashrc`) while on the other it does not.

Answer (score 12):

I'm fairly new to ROS myself and found myself stuck to this issue for 3 weeks. I tried everything I found on forums to no result.
Apparently the issue is that when rosdep update command is skipping updates for the later unsupported ROS distros, such as kinetic. Use the following command to update and then try installing the package again.

> rosdep update --include-eol-distros

Comment: I'm trying to install ROS2 on Ubuntu [from here](https://docs.ros.org/en/dashing/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html) and this worked for me as well.

Comment: you are a demi-god. Matsalams!

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons for this. If you perform the following step you should be able to resolve it:

- Make sure that you **checked out the correct branch** by typing `git branch` after having cloned the repository. It should output `kinetic-devel`. If that is not the case switch to the wished branch `git checkout kinetic-devel`.
- If that is correct make sure that you have **installed `rospy`** with `sudo apt-get install python-rospy`.
- Finally make sure that you have actually **sourced the ROS environment variables** with `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` (or wherever you have installed it) before calling `rosdep install robotiq_modbus_tcp`.
- Else you might give it a try to **install the package from source**: Clone it from the [Github](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/tree/kinetic-devel/robotiq_modbus_tcp) and follow [these instructions](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/).